# Parameter 0 of method filterChain

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, spring-security

I am not able to configure my security class correctly, when I inject @Bean the application does not start, but when I remove @Bean the application starts but does not load my settings

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method filterChain in   com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.config.integracao.security.SpringSecurityV2 required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type  'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Security configuration:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
 public class SpringSecurityV2 {



 @Bean
 public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();



    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

}
```

The pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.14</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.xxxxxxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>xxxxxxxxxx</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>xxxxxxxxxxxx</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>11</java.version>
            <squiggly.version>1.3.18</squiggly.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaybird</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.8.java11</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-community-dialects</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.0.Alpha9</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.11.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.bohnman</groupId>
                <artifactId>squiggly-filter-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.18</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
                <artifactId>byte-buddy-agent</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
                <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
                <version>RELEASE</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            </exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
    </project>
```

Comment: Do you have the correct dependencies?

Comment: `import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;`

Comment: Do you have the `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency in pom.xml? I am not referring to imports.

Comment: please remove the `spring-security-core` it is not needed as you have inccluded the `spring-security-starter` which in turn will pull in all relevant dependencies for you.

Comment: Your dependencies are a mess please clean them oup and fix them. In this case at least remove the `spring-security-core` dependency.

Comment: i fixed my pom.xml and removed spring-security-core but the error still persists

Answer (score 1):

Gateway and Spring Security generate conflicts. If not use gateway Spring security works fine. Someone could  give more reach?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).